# I deleted the the task scheduler registry entries. How do I recover them?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, window

By mistake i have deleted

`\Schedule` folder from `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule]`

What can I do? I want to recover this registry folder.

Comment: Do you have another machine you could export the reg keys from? Have you tried removing and re-adding the Windows Scheduler feature?

Comment: no how can i do this

Answer (score 1):

I can export mine, but I notice that the SID of my user account is inside,
so it may not match yours.

If System Restore is enabled, the best solution would be to rollback
to before the deletion was done, so as to have your local values
returned.

Comment: i had done system  restore but no change

Comment: You perhaps didn't go back far enough.